# How to convert Python time.monotonic to walltime accurately

Tags: python, time

I have a time returned by `time.monotonic()` that I want to convert to walltime (i.e. `time.time()`, suitable for formatting with `time.strftime`). Is there a precise/atomic way to get the offset between both? I know I can just request both `time.monotonic()` and `time.time()` at an arbitrary point in time and calculate the difference, but this is inaccurate because there will be some delay between both calls (quite a lot since Python is slow, even more if there happen to be interrupts/rescheduling).

Comment: By definition, you can't. Docs clearly says that there is no reference. And if you are worried by the time delay between two subsequents calls, then you should be worried even more by the very reason of the existence of `time.monotonic`: system clock may vary. On my system (and I guess almost everyone nowadays) walltime is constantly adjusted from internet

Comment: If you want anyway to compute an offset, and then to count on the absence of any reason for that offset to change (no significative adjustment from internet, no change of system time by user, no leap second occurring while your code run, etc), then you could compute 100 differences `time.time()-time.monotonic()` and 100 differences `-time.monotonic()+time.time()` and compute an olympic average of those (the "olympic" part remove outliers dues to interrupts). But of course it is only a way to reduce inaccuracy, not to remove it.

Comment: `%timeit time.time() - time.time()` says that it takes 146 ns +- 0.6ns per execution on my machine, so that means ~146 ns to execute `time.time()` twice (plus a subtraction), in other words `time.time()` takes less than `146/2 = 73 ns` on average. So I'd say that it should be possible to "calibrate" this to a precision of about ~100 ns. IMHO I would worry much more about `time.time` time fluctuations than the time it takes for the function calls to run if I were you.

Answer (score -2):

```
import time


baseline_monotonic = time.monotonic()
baseline_walltime = time.time()

def monotonic_to_walltime(monotonic_timestamp):

    diff = monotonic_timestamp - baseline_monotonic
    
    estimated_walltime = baseline_walltime + diff
    
    return estimated_walltime
```

Comment: OP literally states "this is inaccurate because there will be some delay between both calls (quite a lot since Python is slow, even more if there happen to be interrupts/rescheduling)."